# Test if 'Device Broadcast Status' in Spotify is toggled

Tags: android, spotify

So I'm currently working with an app that needs to listen for Spotify activity. This is possible if the user has 'Device Broadcast Status' enabled.

What I want to do is to test if the setting is toggled and if not, show a dialog like "If you want to use this feature you need to enable Device Broadcast Status".

There's a similar post here on SO but the question there is if it's possible for another app to change the setting, which is not what I want to do, I just want to know if it's on or off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging at work and No, it's not possible.